# Transferring notes into a particular folder

Tags: iphone, ios, notes.app

I added a new folder in Notes but I don't know how to transfer new or existing notes into the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Tap Edit, select the notes you wish to move to a folder, choose Move To… and pick the destination.

Answer (score 0):

1. Force touch (if not capable, see next sentence) on the note, swipe up, and select "move". If your phone doesn't support force touch, swipe left on the note and select "move".
2. If moving more than one note, press edit, select the notes and select "move to...".
3. If either of these don't work for you (need to have the updated version of notes enabled for above options), you can always select all and cut the note, then create a new one in the desired folder and paste.

Comment: What if the OP doesn't have force-touch?  The question involved 'moving' a note so cut/paste wouldn't work.  In light of not knowing the device, you should edit your answer to include the older devices or ask the OP questions to determine the device.  This will improve your answer as well as increase your chances of getting more upvotes.

Comment: @fsb thanks for the feedback! I added an alternative to force touch for those with older phones. My thinking is that even if OP has older phone, I want my answer to help others who may have newer phones (which is increasingly likely in the future); point being I don't think it's necessary to ask for version. Copying and pasting is effectively the same as moving the note, I used that on iOS before notes updated to allow moving notes on iOS, this is basically a last resort/manual/foolproof way to achieve the desired outcome.